# How to link 'belongs_to' and 'many' in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, model, relationship

2 models:

```
# User Model:
...
many :research_papers
```

and

```
# ResearchPaper Model:
...
key :user_id,  ObjectId
key :username, String

belongs_to :user
```

I want to link the research paper to the user.  I've got the :user_id and :username listed there ...

Do I just insert the ObjectId for the user myself?

```
"_id" : ObjectId("4fb2739045a86e0c5c000002")
```

Lastly how do I verify that I've created a correct link / association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only store the user_id within the research paper model because if the username changed then you'd need to update all their research papers as well as simply the author.

Here is a decent [tutorial](http://blog.fiesta.cc/post/11319522700/walkthrough-mongodb-data-modeling) on modelling with MongoDB

Comment: Good idea on the user_id vrs username comment ... Just to firm it up I'm actually just getting the user_id and inserting it myself?

Comment: Yes. You should end up with something like:

$research_paper = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'MongoDB', 'user_id' => $user->id);
$collection->insert($research_paper);